# Searching Gmail for messages "from" or "to"

Tags: gmail-search

I need a search that finds all messages regarding a particular matter, including messages I sent to several people AND messages I received from several people; subject matter may vary, so I want to search based on sender and recipient.

If I populate the FROM field with the names I want, and populate the TO field with names too, will Gmail find messages to/from any of them, or only messages to AND from any of them?

Answer (score 1):

It really rather depends on how you use `OR` in your search string.

For instance:

```
from:(tom@example.com or mary@example.net or sid@example.org) to:(joe@example.com or steve@example.net or jane@example.org)
```

This search will find any message that's from any one of Tom, Mary or Sid *and* is to any combination of Joe, Steve, or Jane.

If you leave out the `OR` then search will use "AND".

```
to:(joe@example.com steve@example.net jane@example.org)
```

will find all messages that are to Joe, Steve, *and* Jane.

If you want to find messages that are to *or* from someone, you can use

```
from:joe@example.com OR to:joe@example.com
```

This will find all messages that are either to *or* from Joe.

```
from:joe@example.com OR to:(joe@example.com or steve@example.net or jane@example.org)
```

is left as an exercise for the reader.

More information at [Gmail Advanced Search](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190)